# How can I make this script run

Tags: python, html, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I found this script (tutorial) on GitHub (https://github.com/amyoshino/Dash_Tutorial_Series/blob/master/ex4.py) and I am trying to run in my local machine.
Unfortunately I am having and Error
[image]

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me to run this script.
Perhaps this is something easy but I am new in coding.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to `pip install` the dash-core-components library!

Take a look at the [Dash Installation](https://dash.plot.ly/installation) documentation. It currently recommends running these commands:

```sh
pip install dash==0.38.0  # The core dash backend
pip install dash-html-components==0.13.5  # HTML components
pip install dash-core-components==0.43.1  # Supercharged components
pip install dash-table==3.5.0  # Interactive DataTable component (new!)
pip install dash-daq==0.1.0  # DAQ components (newly open-sourced!)
```

For more info on using `pip` to install Python packages, see: [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).

If you *have* run those commands, and Flask still throws that error, you may be having a path/environment issue, and should provide more info in your question about your Python setup.

---

Also, just to give you a sense of how to interpret this error message:

- It's often easiest to start at the bottom and work your way up.
- Here, the bottommost message is a `FileNotFound` error.
- The program is looking for the file in your `Python37/lib/site-packages` folder. That tells you it's looking for a Python package. That is the directory to which Python packages get installed when you use a tool like `pip`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, I have installed all the libraries you are mentioning above. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Then it is likely a path/environment issue. Your flask is installed in `Python37/lib`, but your default `pip` may have installed the other packages elsewhere. You can try using `pip3` instead of `pip`. You may have to provide more info about your Python setup.

Comment: thank you your answer. I was able to run the script. Apparently, I had installed old versions of the library above.

Comment: I have some questions related to script. would you be able to help me?

Comment: I would suggest you ask a new question! Include as much detail as you can, and mention what you have already tried. Good luck!